# PowerShell script not displaying all results

Tags: powershell

I'm running:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName system -Source user32 | Select TimeGenerated -Last 2
Get-WinEvent -ProviderName Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-boot -MaxEvents 10 |
    Where-Object {$_.Message -like “The boot type*”} |
    Select TimeCreated -Last 2
```

But only results from the first command are displayed, regardless of the order. What should I do for the script to display all the results?

Comment: [`... | Out-Default`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/29/how-powershell-formatting-and-outputting-really-works/)

Comment: That worked, thank you!